# Parent UIView in StackView displayed wrong, but its subviews are correct

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem where the frame/layer is shown correctly on iPhone, but not on iPad and iPhone X. Only after going to another view and back to that UIViewController it is shown correctly.

I have a 3 `UIViews` in a `vertical StackView`. The first top 2 are shown correctly. But the third is not. The third `UIView` contains a `containerView` and in it there is a `TableView`. Through the view debugger I can see that the `containerView` and the `tableView` have the correct frame, but it looks like the parent UIView is not redrawn correctly.

Here is a screenshot of the `view debugger` from the front of that `UIView`. The `UIView` with the red background is the one displayed incorrect (correct after going away and back to that UIViewController).

[UIView with red background incorrect (Frame is correct, but displayed wrong). The subviews have the correct frame. I set a backgroundcolor to those subviews and these are redrawn correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj8xG.png)

Here the same view from the back:

[UIView in question from behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPt36.png)

I tried `.setNeedsDisplay.`, `.setNeedsLayout`, followed by `.setLayoutIfNeeded`. Running those in main thread, but didn't got success so far.

I am using Swift 4 and iOS 11. As I said this is in a vertical StackView. The first 2 UIViews have a height constraint, this one, has no constraint as it should fill the rest.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved for iPad and iPhone X, removing the shadow layer on the view that was drawn incorrectly.